# Number of generators greater than the number of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

> Show that if we pick in a vector space a set of generators and a set of linearly independent vectors that the number of generators is greater than or equal to the number of linearly independent vectors.

---

My question is whether or not the proof I came up with for this is (a) correct, (b) too convoluted:

**Proof**:

Take a vector space $V$.

Let $B = \left\{e_1,e_2,...,e_n\right\} \subset V$ where the elements of $B$ are generators of $V$ and $G = \left\{v_1,v_2,...,v_k\right\} \subset V$ where the elements of $G$ are linearly independent vectors.

By the definition of systems of generators, any vector in a vector space can be expressed as a linear combination of generators. So any element in $G$ can be expressed as a linear combination of elements in $B$.

Since the elements of $G$ are linearly independent of one another, it follows that each $v_i \in G$ is given by a linear combination of a unique subset of elements of $B$; that is no single element of $B$ is used in any more than one linear combination of elements giving a vector in $G$.

Assume that $\#B < \#G$. This contradicts the above since there will be at least one element in $B$ which is used in more than one linear combination that gives an element of $G$, contradicting the uniqueness of these combinations.

$\therefore \#B \geq \#G$ by contradiction. $\square$

Comment: I'll say your proof is correct.

Comment: This is not a proof, this is a hand-wavy argument to convince yourself and a friend. It **can** be made a proof using induction, though.

Comment: What must I show mathematically when using induction to prove this? Something to do with $a_1e_1 + a_2e_2 + ...$(where $a_i$ is some constant)?

Comment: Use induction in $n$ and show that $\#G \leq n.$ $n = 1$ is obvious.

On a side note, I find it amusing how I said this is not a proof at all and other people say it was a correct proof. Generally speaking, I am quite formal, so it is expected I wouldn't take an argument like this as a proof. At the end, it boils down to who is marking you. If it were someone like me, I'd give you 1 mark for trying.

Comment: Is it possible to prove by contradiction?

Comment: You must be quite new to prove things; a proof is a proof, it does not matter how you phrase it.

Comment: So there's no difference between proving by induction and proving by contradiction?

Answer (score 1):

The proof is not correct.  The statement that no element of $B$ can be used in more than one linear combination giving a vector of $G$ is not true.  Suppose $B$ and $G$ are two different bases of $V$.  If we accept your statement, we must conclude each element of $G$ is a scalar multiple of some element of $B$, which is false.

Comment: I don't understand why we must conclude that they are equal. You could have multiple elements in B that are used in the same combination giving an element in G without contradiction the assumption, right?

Comment: @s If $B$ and $G$ are both bases, they have the same number of elements.  If you can use each element of $B$ only once, they you can't use more than one.  So each element of $G$ is a scalar multiple of an element of $B$.  (I said the bases are the same; that was a mistake, which I'll correct.)

Comment: Ok, but for the vectors in G to be linearly independent, mustn't the generators used to generate them be linearly independent of each other too?

Comment: @sandbag66 I don't understand what you mean, nor what is has to do with the question.

Comment: Ignore that last comment; what I meant to ask was: if the statement that "no element of $B$ can be used in more than one linear combination giving a vector of $G$" is false, then what is the true condition? I don't know.